# Как и чем лучше всего извлечь таблицы с веб-странички с помощью Python и его библиотек?

Tags: python, python-3.x, table

Есть три небольшие таблицы на [этом сайте](https://www.calc.ru/kurs-Brent-online.html), которые хотелось бы спарсить максимально простым способом. После чего их можно было бы выводить в виде своей таблицы или даже графика. Пробовал извлекать их просто с помощью такого кода:

```
import pandas as pd
tables = pd.read_html("https://www.calc.ru/kurs-Brent-online.html", header=0,)
print(tables)
```

но получалась ерунда, скорее всего потому, что этот запрос пытался мне выдать всю страничку.

Как это лучше сделать?

Comment: А зачем он вам, он же обновляется раз в минуту? или вы собираетесь каждый раз обновлять информацию?

Comment: А так используйте библиотеку request + Beautiful Soup 4 для разбора страницы, либо request + lxml

Comment: @danilshik Думал после извлечения просто всю конструкцию положить в цикл который бы перезапускал эту часть кода каждую минуту или что-то вроде этого

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Попробуйте все тем же Pandas:

```
df = pd.read_html("https://www.calc.ru/kurs-Brent-online.html", 
                  encoding='cp1251',
                  header=0)[7]

# minutely
m = pd.Series(df.iloc[2, :10].astype(float).values, index=df.iloc[1, :10].values)
# hourly
h = pd.Series(df.iloc[5, :10].astype(float).values, index=df.iloc[4, :10].values)
# daily
d = pd.Series(df.iloc[8, :10].astype(float).values, index=df.iloc[7, :10].values)
```

результат:

```
In [232]: m
Out[232]:
16:05    76.20
16:04    76.20
16:03    76.20
16:02    76.20
16:00    76.14
15:59    76.14
15:58    76.14
15:57    76.14
15:55    76.16
15:54    76.16
dtype: float64

In [233]: h
Out[233]:
15:54    76.16
15:42    76.27
15:29    76.29
15:17    76.14
15:04    76.34
14:52    76.36
14:39    76.44
14:27    76.53
14:14    76.20
14:02    76.06
dtype: float64

In [234]: d
Out[234]:
14:52    76.36
13:37    75.83
12:17    75.59
11:02    75.79
09:45    75.86
08:30    75.85
07:15    75.72
06:00    75.64
04:45    75.50
03:30    75.88
dtype: float64
```

Comment: Спасибо, это мне помогло, буду разбираться)